# How to get the browser to stop caching server responses?

Tags: html, http, caching, webserver, browser-cache

I developed my own custom web server for a robot I built ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMI4oVpQ6So)), without really knowing the intricacies of HTTP.  One issue I am running into is I send a request from a browser, say, `http://192.168.2.10/r?cmd=doStuff` and the robot responds.  Then I send the same request again from the browser (by clicking on a bookmark I saved), and the request never goes out, it just shows the response from the previous request.

Here is what comes from the browser (IE8 in particular):

```
GET /r?cmd=s HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg,     application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zune 4.7)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 192.168.2.10
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The robot responds with the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: The Little Robot That Could 1.0
Date: Thu, 01 Jan 2009 00:05:00 GMT
Content-Length: 4
X-Powered-By: Little Robot HTTP Server
```

Do I need to throw some other HTTP header into the mix to prevent the browser from caching the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need cache-control header.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache;max-age=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try throwing in a Pragma: no-cache. Should work on any modern browser.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: pragma: no-cache is obsolete (http 1.0). it's only used due to IE6 issues and old proxy servers. "HTTP/1.1 caches SHOULD treat 'Pragma: no-cache' as if the client had sent 'Cache-Control: no-cache'. No new Pragma directives will be defined in HTTP. "

Comment: Oops, I meant to specify to use if IE6 is supported. Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Well.

The *real* problem here is using GET for "do something".